# Dismiss AlertDialog without clicking on button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'd like to dismiss an AlertDialog window, but not when clicking on the "ok" or "cancel" button, but when an action is called.
In fact, I'd like to create the dialog in onResume function that way :

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alert.setTitle("Stay stuck to a tag");
    alert.create().show();
}
```

and then exit it when a function is called, like

```
private void dismissMyDiag() {
    alert.dismiss();
}
```

Of course I've seen the way to do that with the onclick event by that's not what I want to do.
Is it possible to do such a thing ? And if not, what king of dialog box allows me to do that ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is there an AsyncTask, or another kind of background process, that may call dismissMyDiag()?

Comment: When does that method gets called? Async task? Or in the main activity? Have you thought of using Threads?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the alertDialog like this

```
AlertDialog dialog;
 alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

dialog=alert.create().show();
```

Then call

```
private void dismissMyDiag() {
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it ! Just to be more precise, it's something like alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
  dialog = alert.create();
  dialog.show();

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.my_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                        new Dialog.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                                //Do nothing here. We override the onclick
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                .create();

        d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

                Button b = d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        // TODO Do something

                        //Dismiss once everything is OK.
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i know it's old Question but may Hope This will help Some One.
You Can also Can Create A Custom Class For Alert Dialog And Access it hole project
Can Show and hide any where

```
package (Your_Pakage_Name);
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;


public class AlertDailogbox extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

    String Title = null;
    String Msg = null;
    String TAG = "Alert Dialog Box";

    public AlertDailogbox(String title, String msg) {
        Title = title;
        Msg = msg;
        
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(Title)
                .setMessage(Msg)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_alert) //set icon if you want
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Call in Your Project (Activity)
Make an Global Variable of alertDialog Class

```
private AlertDailogbox alertDailogbox;
```

function to show Dialog

```
private void showMsgDailog(String Title,String Msg){
    alertDailogbox = new AlertDailogbox(Title,Msg);
    alertDailogbox.setCancelable(false);
    alertDailogbox.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"alert Dailog");
}
```

End For Dismiss

```
if(alertDailogbox != null)
       alertDailogbox.dismiss();
```

alerDailogeBox is not null check is nessary other wise application can crash